# Does the iOS simulator correct handle the tap event with Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have added a GestureRecognizer like this:

```
    faveLabel.Text = "ABC";
    faveLabel.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        faveLabel.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command(() => OnLabelClicked())
        });

    }

    private void OnLabelClicked()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Here is the XAML:

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="15,10,20,10" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
   <Label x:Name="faveLabel" XAlign="Center" FontSize="23" />
</StackLayout>
```

Using the simulator it almost never works and when I did get it to work it seemed like I had to click above the text and not on the text.  When I debug on my phone it works okay.

Are there some issues where the simulator does not respond correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no issues that I know of. I haven't seen any weird myself unless I actually had something else causing it. You could try to give your `Label` a bright background color to see where it is actually positioned. Perhaps some of your other elements are overlapping it or something else in your UI is stopping the gesture recognizer. A common example is when you put one in a ListView which has a tap event of its own which might conflict with a `TapGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: Hi Steven.  "Not that I know of",  Do you mean you don't think it works?  Sorry I was a bit confused with the first words. Thanks

Comment: It was aimed towards your last comment "Are there some issues where the simulator does not respond correctly?". So no, there are no issues that I know of :)